# Android Java code to connect to nearby esp8266 AP

Tags: android, permissions, esp8266, wifimanager

I have a esp8266 running in AP mode I gave it a static name for all other devices, I want my android app to connect to this esp8266 AP just by clicking on pair button, the problem is I'm not familiar with android versions so in some APIs it may work but on higher APIs like 29 and above the WiFiManager functions are deprecated, so I am looking for a way to write a single code which regardless of the API version it works for all, for example user turns the esp8266 on and in android clicks on pair then the app gives the SSID as a suggestion or automatically connects using static SSID.

Comment: Your Android device can connect with the esp device. After that your Android app can connect to a server application on the esp device.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, I don't want the user to go to their phones settings to connect to esp, I want them to be connected to esp by simply pushing a button in the android app